# Expression related to triangular inequality!

Tags: calculus, limits

How is this true??
$$2=|1-(-1)|=|(1-L)+(L-(-1))|\leq|1-L|+|-1-L|$$
The part I do not understand is $|-1-L|$!! How??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|L-(-1)|=|L+1|=|-1|\cdot|L+1|=|(-1)(L+1)|=|-L-1|$$

Comment: Are we allow to multiply |(-1)|??

Comment: @eChung00: Sure, why not? $|-1|=1$, so multiplying by it doesn’t change anything.

Comment: @eChung00: You’re welcome!